# How to get multiple result sets from a stored procedure into another table

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure returns 3 sets of data when executing. That time I want 2nd set of results to some temp table.

For example: my stored procedure is returning these result sets:

```
-----------------------------
Sno   EmpName    EmpNo
-----------------------------
1      Test1      101
2      Test2      102

---------------------------------
ID  StudentName  StudentDOB
---------------------------------
1     abc1        10-10-2020
2     xyz         14-12-2018

----------------------------------------------------------
Sno   Start_Time              End_Time            Duration
----------------------------------------------------------
1     10-10-2021 10:00:00   10-10-2021 10:10:00     10
2     10-10-2021 10:00:00   10-10-2021 10:15:00     15
```

I want to get 2nd set of results into some temp table. How to get only a particular result set?

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM test1
    SELECT * FROM test2
    SELECT * FROM test3
END
```

Exec test   --> I want to get test2 only test2 table results set to another temp table.

Comment: Stored Procedure (SQL Server)

Comment: My SQL Stored procedure return multiple table format result sets. I want to take only necessary table set. How to get it?

Comment: There is no way of doing this in TSQL. If you are doing this for testing and using tSQLt you can use `tSQLt.ResultSetFilter` but this ends up using CLR to do it. For a TSQL only solution either break down your proc into multiple procs that can be called individually or add a parameter to allow suppressing of unwanted resultset

Comment: You need to explain further in what context you are trying to access these results in a temp table and what you have researched and tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Just pass a paramter to yor SP to indicate if it should return the resultset or insert into temp table.

Comment: This is my requirement. Actually i can't modify existing stored procedure. When i am executing that procedure i am getting 3 set of results. I want to create single table to insert all result sets to that new table. For Example. you can see my post with sample result 3 set of results. I want to copy the values into another new table for all colunns. Sno,EmpName,Empno,ID,StudentName,StudentDOB, Sno1, Start_Time              End_Time,  Duration.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly from my point of view it's not a good approach or solution that one stored procedure return more than one table result.

Any object on your solution (stored procedure, function, view, etc.) should has only one responsability, so the recomendation it's you try to split the stored procedure.

In fact when I review the data result the 3 result return different columns. I agree with the comment of Stu that you can use a parameter on your SP to indicate wich result, but insist that is not a good solution.

Ok, you can't change the stored procedure, so, one solution can be.
1.- Create a temp table with the same structure that the result.
2.- then you can insert the result inside of your table.
something like this.

```
    --stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 1 as A, 2 AS B

SELECT 2 as C, 2 as D
END
GO

--creating the temp table 
CREATE table #tmpResult
(field1 int null, field2 int null)
GO

-- the query into temp
INSERT INTO #tmpResult(field1, field2)
EXEC  test 
GO

SELECT * FROM #tmpResult
```

the problem is that your SP return 3 diferent structure .